# Accessing unmanaged object from a different thread throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, realm

I have following RealmObjects in my project

```
class A extends RealmObject {
   ...
   private B b;
   private RealmList<C> c;
   //Getter and Setters
}

class B extends RealmObject {
   ...
   private RealmList<D> d;
   //Getter and Setters
}

class C extends RealmObject {
   ...
   private String str1;
   private String str2;
   //Getter and Setter
}

class D extends RealmObject {
   ...
   private String str1;
   private String str2;
   //Getter and Setter
}
```

I'm getting list of `A` from Realm like following:

```
Realm.where(A.class).findAllSortedAsync("sortField", Sort.DESCENDING)
              .asObservable().filter(items -> items.isLoaded())
              .map(new Func1<RealmResults<A>, List<A>>() {
                 @Override
                 public List<A> call(RealmResults<A> realmResults) {
                    return Realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);
                 }
               })
               .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
               .map(new Func1<List<A>, Object object>() {
                 @Override
                 public Object call(List<A> items) {
                   for (A item : items) {
                     item.get(...);
                     item.set(...);
                   }
                 }
               }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(...);
```

When I run the above code, following exception is thrown:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxComputationScheduler-2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
   at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:353)
   at io.realm.RealmResults.checkForAddRemoveListener(RealmResults.java:138)
   at io.realm.RealmResults.removeChangeListener(RealmResults.java:171)
   at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$6$2.call(RealmObservableFactory.java:156)
   at rx.subscriptions.BooleanSubscription.unsubscribe(BooleanSubscription.java:71)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:136)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:125)
   at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:136)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:125)
   at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:136)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:125)
   at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:136)
   at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:125)
   at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:72)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:224)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:172)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
```

Seeing as how the exception is thrown on computation thread, i guess it occurs when I try to access the object of `A` class. I don't understand how this could happen as i have already converted the managed RealmResults to unmanaged List, so accessing it in other thread should not be a problem as mentioned in the Realm wiki.

> Unmanaged objects are just like ordinary Java objects, they are not persisted and they will not be updated automatically. They can be moved freely across threads.

My question is how i can get an unmanaged list of objects from RealmResults which can be accessed from other threads and what I'm doing wrong in the above implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
}).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
 .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // this
 .subscribe(...);
```

Although considering you are copying out your results on the UI thread, maybe I should give this question a bit more thought when I find a keyboard.

EDIT: Okay, I think it should work like this:

```
    realm.where(A.class).findAllAsync()
          .asObservable()
          .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .map(new Func1<RealmResults<A>, List<A>>() {
             @Override
             public List<A> call(RealmResults<A> ignored) {
                try(Realm bgRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                    return bgRealm.copyFromRealm(
                        bgRealm.where(A.class).findAllSorted("sortField", Sort.DESCENDING)
                    );
                }
             }
           })
           .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
           .map(new Func1<List<A>, Object>() {
             @Override
             public Object call(List<A> items) {
               for (A item : items) {
                 item.get(...);
                 item.set(...);
               }
             }
           })
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Still getting the exception.

Comment: That can't be right. Maybe a different one is also missing this unsubscribeOn

Comment: What does adding `unsubscribeOn` achieve?

Comment: If you read the stack trace, it says the problem is that when you unsubscribe the `asObservable()`, then the unsubscription happens on a different thread than the `asObservable` call

Comment: I added my "solution" thing that you probably should be doing

Comment: It worked! I thought of your solution before but it seemed like a waste to ignore the original results and re-fetch them. But I still don't understand what was causing the error and what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

With method `Realm.where(A.class).findAllSortedAsync("sortField", Sort.DESCENDING)`, this will happen in main thread.

With method `map ... return Realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);` , Rx will run map method in another thread, so error happens:

> Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed
>   on the thread they were created.

If you want to run in another thread, you can work around by create another instance of Realm in that thread, like this

```
map(new Func1<RealmResults<A>, List<A>>() {
                 @Override
                 public List<A> call(RealmResults<A> realmResults) {
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    try {
                        realm.beginTransaction();

                        // Your code here

                        realm.commitTransaction();
                    } finally {
                        realm.close();
                    }
                                     }
               })
```

Comment: I've just confirmed `map ... return Realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);` runs in main thread. Also see the first line of stacktrace `FATAL EXCEPTION: RxComputationScheduler-2`, the exception is happening in the second map which runs on the computation thread, so i'm pretty sure the exception is thrown there.